# How to check if someone is using files which you have shared in homegroup?

Tags: windows-7, homegroup

How to check if someone is using files which you have shared in homegroup?

How many ppl use these files, which file are they using?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in real time or statistical information?

Comment: In real time. But ultimately I've switched to local FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on real time, **Resource Monitor** would help. On **Disk** tab you can see which file are being read, and on **Network** tab you can see who are receiving data from you. But it's basic.

If you want to be more thorough, and getting the statistic, in the properties of your shared folder, select **Security** tab, **Advanced**, on **Auditing** tab, add the users you want to track on. Now open `gpedit.msc`, on **Local Computer Policy** → **Computer Configuration** → **Windows Settings** → **Security Settings** → **Local Policies** → **Audit Policy** → **Audit System Events**, check both **Success** and **Failure**.

The log will be in **Security** node of **Event Viewer**. This may cause problem if your log size become too large from all the activity, and I'm not sure if Windows could determine the remote user (more likely only as `Everyone`).

Answer (score 2):

On the server with the file shared:

- Go to **start** > **Run** > type **compmgmt.msc**
- Under '**System Tools**' expand '**Shared Folders**'
- Go to '**Open Files**' that lists all the files in use by network users